# DropDownList on masterpage - don't want it to update everytime

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I'm having a little problem in my web app development. On my masterpage I have a DropDownList. Let's call it MyDDL. When I first load my app (after login) I populate it with some data from SQL database table, let's call it MyTable. No problem there. On my masterpage I also have a menu that redirects user to different pages (content) of my app. When user first selects a value from MyDDL I need it to remain no matter on wich page user clicks (because data on that page is dependand on value selected in MyDDL). Problem I have is, value in MyDDL is reset to "default" (first value in MyTable) everytime I load different page. Is there a way to solve this? Any help is appritiated.

Here is my code behind the masterpage:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        bind();
    }
}

public void bind()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConn"].ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    try
    {
        MyDDL.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        MyDDL.DataTextField = "izdelek";
        MyDDL.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem.

But i suggest you to used [session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87069683%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) Or [querystring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) also check this link for querystring [querystring msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx#Y202).

OnSelectedIndexChanged of dropdownlist save value in session or pass it to webpage using querystring.

On masterpage as you give datasource to dropdownlist and then bind it after that use:

```
MyDDL.selectedvalue = session["SelectId"].tostring() OR request.querystring["SelectId"].tostring().
```

Hope it helps to solve your problem.